# How can I add Google+ to the share menu of Photoshop Elements 9?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-elements

Is there a way to extend the "Share Menu" of PSE 9 to add Google+ or other sharing services? At the moment there are only options to share with Facebook, Flickr, Kodak Easy Share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ uses Picasa for photo albums. Using the **Share > Email Attachments** feature in Photoshop Elements 9, you can send images to your Google account if you have set up [Email Upload](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=83342).